# Mongodb query to remove redundant fields with timestamp less than 1 sec from final result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Name of collections I have
**1) Device:**
_id, deviceId(string), deviceInfo, companyId(string)

**2) Mobile:**
_id, companyId(string), tagId(string), mobileInfo

**3) Tracking:** 
_id, DeviceID(string), TagID(string), trackInfo, Timestamp( is on millisec)

I need to build a query to get all tracking data( with mobile data and device data ) of given companyId. Each company has:

1. One or multiple mobile data with different tagId.
2. One or multiple device data with deviceId.
3. One or multiple tracking data identified by TagID and DeviceID.

Final result should contain fields as listed : 
DeviceID, deviceInfo, companyId, TagID, mobileInfo, trackInfo, Timestamp.
**Condition to be applied on query:**
Tracking collections can have docs of each second, there are the cases where all fields are same (except Timestamp is different by 1 sec).I don't want those redundant looking docs, to achieve this 
we can use condition as : **If adjacent rows of final results are the same with or without their timestamp’s difference is less than 1 sec, then one of the rows shouldn't be on the final result.** I have working query which will return docs with above fields but for redundancy behavior I checked after applying query using loop on docs returned by query as below. Now, I need the following logic to be implemented on query itself.
**Note**: Tracking collections has millions of docs so beware of the query which could impact on performance.

```js
// grid is the array of documents returned by mongodb using query.
for (var k=1;k<grid.length;){
    var a=Number(grid[k].Timestamp);
    var b=Number(grid[k-1].Timestamp)
    if ((Math.abs(a - b)<(1000)) && grid[k].TagID===grid[k-1].TagID && grid[k].DeviceID===grid[k-1].DeviceID){
        grid.splice(k, 1);
    }
    else{
        k++;
    }
}

    
for (var k=1;k<grid.length-1;){
    if ((grid[k].DeviceID===grid[k-1].DeviceID && grid[k].TagID===grid[k-1].TagID) && (grid[k].DeviceID===grid[k+1].DeviceID && grid[k].TagID===grid[k+1].TagID)){
        grid.splice(k, 1);
    }
    else{
        k++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, can you share the query you currently have? The one that is generating the result you are using in the loop.

Comment: @OTZ First I query mobile collection to get mobile docs matching given companyId. Like this: Mobile.find({companyId : givenOne }).   
Query device collection to get devices docs matching given companyId. 
Device.find({companyId : givenOne }). 
Then finally I query tracking collections to get docs where TagID is in mobile docs tagId and DeviceID in device docs deviceId. Tracking.find({TagID: { $in: mobileDocsTagId }, DeviceID: { $in: deviceDocsTagId }).
For final result's fields, I used another loop to add mobileInfo, deviceInfo on trackingDocs.

Comment: Due to large number of docs I end up using multiple query like this as using lookup it took more than 5 mins to give response by db.